# Symfony Deprecation on SessionTokenStorage when generating a csrf token in phpunit functionnal tests

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I'm on symfony 5.4

I didn't understand what symfony really need in order to correct this deprecation:

> Since symfony/security-csrf 5.3: Using the "Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\TokenStorage\SessionTokenStorage" without a session has no effect and is deprecated. It will throw a "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Exception\SessionNotFoundException" in Symfony 6.0
> 1x in MeansCablesControllerTest::TestDatagridAdd from App\Tests\Controller

My function in  tests/Controller/MeansBenchesControllerTest.php  (WebTestCase) :

```
function datagridAddUpdate($controllerName, $dataArray)
    {
        $client = static::createClient();
        
        $usersRepository = static::getContainer()->get(UsersRepository::class);
        $testUserAdmin = $usersRepository->find(1);
        
        $client->loginUser($testUserAdmin);

        $csrfToken = $client->getContainer()->get('security.csrf.token_manager')->getToken($controllerName.'Token_item');

        $dataArray['_token'] = $csrfToken;

        $crawler = $client->request('POST', '/datagridAddUpdate/'.$controllerName,$dataArray, [], ['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH' => 'XMLHttpRequest']);

        $this->assertResponseIsSuccessful('Status code 2xx pour datagridAdd : '.$controllerName);

    }
```

Comment: By requesting the page vía `GET` and using [Crawler's `form()` function](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html#forms) you can also get the token and bypass the deprecation, there's no need to generate it on the sidelines.

Comment: yes it can be a solution but it doesn't fully answer the question. it can be interresting to undestand what symofny need and how to implement it ;)

Comment: That's the solution I had to choose in the interim, since as far as I know, there's no 'official' replacement. Now accessing the session requires the RequestStack, but I think that wouldn't work in this scenario as there's no request until... you know... request the page. There are [a couple](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/discussions/44592) of [related discussions](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/discussions/44963) in [github](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/44253) but no (merged) alternatives so far. So I'd appreciate if you posted and answer when you find one.

Comment: as a temporary solution i made a route only in test environment that return the token value with a given string, so i can use it in my tests and no need to get the token from the form. That was also useful for ajax route testing.

Answer (score 2):

Running this before building the form will make sure there is a session available for it:

```php
$request = new Request();
$request->setSession(new Session(new MockArraySessionStorage()));

self::getContainer()->get(RequestStack::class)->push($request);
```

Comment: This did not work for me, unfortunately, and I am still at a loss

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, @bart's answer didn't work for me. It effectively suppressed the deprecation warning, but it creates a separate session from the `loginUser()` session. My goal was to log in, and then be able to set session values on the common logged in session.

I figured out a workaround for my use case, documented here: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/discussions/46961

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\KernelBrowser;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Cookie;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

abstract class AbstractWebTestCase extends WebTestCase
{
    private KernelBrowser $client;
    private SessionInterface $session;
    
    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->client = static::createClient();
        ...
    }

    ...

    /**
     * This replicates static::createClient()->loginUser()
     * Inspect that method, as there are additional checks there that may be necessary for your use case.
     * The magic here is tracking an internal $session object that can be updated as needed.
     */
    protected function loginUser(UserInterface $user): void
    {   
        $token = new TestBrowserToken($user->getRoles(), $user, $firewallContext);
        $container = static::getContainer();
        $container->get('security.untracked_token_storage')->setToken($token);

    $this->session = $container->get('session.factory')->createSession();
        $this->setLoginSessionValue('_security_'.$firewallContext, serialize($token));

        $domains = array_unique(array_map(function (Cookie $cookie) {
            return $cookie->getName() === $this->session->getName() ? $cookie->getDomain() : '';
        }, $this->client->getCookieJar()->all())) ?: [''];
        
        foreach ($domains as $domain) {
            $cookie = new Cookie($this->session->getName(), $this->session->getId(), null, null, $domain);
            $this->client->getCookieJar()->set($cookie);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /** @param mixed $value */
    protected function setLoginSessionValue(string $name, $value): self
    {
        if (isset($this->session)) {
            $this->session->set($name, $value);
            $this->session->save();
            return $this;
        }
        throw new \LogicException("loginUser() must be called to initialize session");
    }

    ...
}
```

And now we can update the session:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\TokenStorage\SessionTokenStorage;

class MyWebTest extends AbstractWebTestCase
{
    public function testSomething(): void
    {
        $user = ...;
        $this->loginUser($user);
        
        // Technically, you don't need to generate a real token here, and instead could use any test string
        $tokenId = ...;
        $csrfToken = static::getContainer()->get('security.csrf.token_generator')->generateToken();
        $this->setLoginSessionValue(SessionTokenStorage::SESSION_NAMESPACE . "/$tokenId", $csrfToken);

        // Now you can make raw POST requests without crawling to the form page first!
    }
}
```