# Session in Symfony (5.3/5.4) functional tests

Tags: phpunit, functional-testing, symfony5

### Background

I updated from Symfony 5.3 to Symfony 5.4.

Since then I get an error message, when I start my PHPunit-tests.

### The error message

```
Since symfony/framework-bundle 5.3: Accessing the "session" 
service directly from the container is deprecated, use 
dependency injection instead.
```

### The code of my test

```php
class BookingControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testBookingStep4()
    {
        // ...

        // create the CLIENT
        self::ensureKernelShutdown();
        $this->client  = static::createClient();

        // generate CART (simulating previous steps)
        $cart = $this->generateCart($person, $items);

        // put CART into SESSION
        $session = $this->client->getContainer()->get('session'); // <-- THROWS THE WARNING
        $session->set('cart', $cart);

        // make the REQUEST (which is using the data in the session)
        $this->client->request('GET', "booking/finalization");
        $this->assertResponseStatusCodeSame(200);

        // ...
    }
}
```

### What I did so far ...

```php
   // tried to replace this line
   $session = $this->client->getContainer()->get('session');

   // by this and ...
   $session = $this->client->getContainer()->get('request_stack')->getSession();

   // by this and ...
   $session = $this->client->getContainer()->get(RequestStack::class)->getSession();

   // by that
   $session = new Session(new MockFileSessionStorage());
```

No solutions solved the issue.

### Solution (open)

What can I do? Anybody an idea?

###### Appendix (the controller that gets tested)

```php
class BookingController extends AbstractController 
{

    private $cart;

    /**
     * @Route("booking/finalization", name="app_booking_finalization")
     */
    public function booking_finalization(Request $request, RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        $session    = $requestStack->getSession();
        $this->cart = $session->get('cart');

        // check requirements
        $isValid = $this->bookingHelper->isCartValid($this->cart);

        // redirect if requirements are not fulfilled
        if (!$isValid) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_booking_checkout');
        }

        // ...

}
```

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70669443) is the same but for 5.4 where it's a deprecation instead of an error. I added some links to discussions that might be useful to keep an eye on.